# How to use tidyr in Rstudio to seperate a column with numbers and characters?

Tags: r, tidyr

[image: player column]

So I am using tidyr in Rstudio and I am trying to separate the data in the 'player' column (attached below) into 4 individual columns: 'number', 'name','position' and 'school'. I tried using the separate() function, but can't get the number to separate and can't use a str_sub because some numbers are double digits. Does anyone know how to separate this column to the appropriate 4 columns?

Comment: Please don't show data as images.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data do not count as "reproducible" since we can't copy/paste the data for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method using a series of `separate` calls.

```
# Example data
df <- data.frame(
  player = c('11Vita VeaDT | Washington',
             '16Clelin FerrellEDGE | Clemson',
             "17K'Lavon ChaissonEdge | LSU",
             '15Cody FordOT | Oklahoma',
             '20Derrius GuiceRB',
             '1Joe BurrowQB | LSU'))
```

The steps are:

1. separate `school` using `|`
2. separate `number` using the distinction of numbers and letters
3. separate `position` using capital and lowercase, but starting at the end
4. cleanup, trim off white space, or extra spaces around the text

```
df %>%
  separate(player, into = c('player', 'school'), '\\|') %>%
  separate(player, into = c('number', 'player'), '(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])') %>%
  separate(player, into = c('last', 'position'), '(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])') %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, trimws)
```

```
# Results
   number         name position      school
1  11         Vita Vea       DT  Washington
2  16   Clelin Ferrell     EDGE     Clemson
3  17 K'Lavon Chaisson     Edge         LSU
4  15        Cody Ford       OT    Oklahoma
5  20    Derrius Guice       RB        <NA>
6   1       Joe Burrow       QB         LSU
```